# Moving files based on them being present in folders

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to move multiple files from multiple folders. When a file is present, it should first be renamed, and then be moved. If not, then nothing should happen (so the bat script doesn't error out).

I've already written a script, it works when using them independently, but not when I add everything together. Could anyone guide me in the right direction?

```
    @echo on
    if exist C:\DATA\FTP\311\*.xlsx 
    (
    ren C:\DATA\FTP\311\To_Process\*.xlsx ??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????_311.xlsx 
    MOVE /Y C:\DATA\FTP\311\To_Process\*.xlsx C:\DATA\FTP\To_Process
    )
    if exist C:\DATA\FTP\312\*.xlsx 
    (
    ren C:\DATA\FTP\312\To_Process\*.xlsx ??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????_312.xlsx
    MOVE /Y C:\DATA\FTP\312\To_Process\*.xlsx C:\DATA\FTP\To_Process
    )
    if exist C:\DATA\FTP\313\*.xlsx
    (
    ren C:\DATA\FTP\313\To_Process\*.xlsx ??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????_313.xlsx
    MOVE /Y C:\DATA\FTP\313\To_Process\*.xlsx C:\DATA\FTP\To_Process
    )
    if exist C:\DATA\FTP\314\*.xlsx
    (
    ren C:\DATA\FTP\311\To_Process\*.xlsx ??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????_314.xlsx
    MOVE /Y C:\DATA\FTP\315\To_Process\*.xlsx C:\DATA\FTP\To_Process
    )
    if exist C:\DATA\FTP\315\*.xlsx
    (
    ren C:\DATA\FTP\315\To_Process\*.xlsx ??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????_315.xlsx
    MOVE /Y C:\DATA\FTP\314\To_Process\*.xlsx C:\DATA\FTP\To_Process
    )
    if exist C:\DATA\FTP\320\*.xlsx
    (
    ren C:\DATA\FTP\320\To_Process\*.xlsx ??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????_320.xlsx
    MOVE /Y C:\DATA\FTP\320\To_Process\*.xlsx C:\DATA\FTP\To_Process
)
```

Thanks!

Comment: move all of your opening parenthesis `(` to the the if stament line. The if statement does not know that the command to perform is on the next line only. `if exist C:\DATA\FTP\311\*.xlsx (`

Comment: you could have however skipped all the `if exist` code blocks and just run a simple for loop to achieve the same results..

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Tried that, but actually even one of the if statements doesn't seem to work anymore. :/

Comment: @GerhardBarnard But I have to rename the files based on the folder they are in, don't think that's possible?

Comment: off course it is possible :)

Comment: Technically, it is impossible in Windows, because you cannot have a file or directory containing the character **`?`**. When you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55722456/edit) to better explain, *instead of allowing us to guess*, you can fix your code which contains typos of the type that make your task sequence/pattern inconsistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with your script causing it to now work and one problem that is seems to be a very manual method.

*Problem 1:*

The opening parenthesis should be on the same line as your `if` statement, i.e:

```
if exist C:\DATA\FTP\311\*.xlsx (
```

*Problem 2:*

You are searching for files inside of the root `C:\DATA\FTP` but then attempt to rename files in `C:\DATA\FTP\To_Process` when they should be renamed from the root of `FTP`

Anyway, here is a slightly modified version, a little more Automated.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F %%i in ('dir /b /s *.xlsx' ^| findstr /vi "FTP\To_process") do (
    set "fol=%%~pi"
    set "fol=!fol:~0,-1!"
    for %%a in (!fol!) do set res=%%~na
        echo ren "%%~fi" "%%~dpni_!res!%%~xi"
        echo move /y "%%~ni_!res!%%~xi" "C:\DATA\FTP\To_Process"
   )
```

Some things to **note**:
Place this batch file in the root of `C:\DATA\FTP`

The two second last lines start with `echo` for testing purpose, remove them only once happy that the code will do what you expect it to.

There is a `findstr /vi` command in the for loop, this is to ensure we exclude renaming files that already exists in `C:\DATA\FTP\To_process`

Lastly, I am a little unclear whether your files are localted in `C:\DATA\FTP\NNN\` or if they are in `C:\DATA\FTP\NNN\To_process` So clarification on that will simplify it for me to give 100% complete script as for now, this script assumes the files are in `C:\DATA\FTP\NNN`